# Need a javascript/HTML 5 web player that plays audio with G.711 codec wrapped in WAV container

Tags: javascript, html, audio, embed, wav

I'm looking for a javascript/HTML5 embeddedable player with the libraries to play audio with G.711 codec wrapped in WAV container.  So far standard HTML5 does not support this type of audio.  Does anyone have any suggestion of any players/libraries?  Paid or free suggestions welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the codec/format/wrapper is not supported natively by the browsers you are aiming it will never work. You should convert your audio file in a format natively supported by most of the browsers.

http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

Comment: ... and if it's live (realdata) data you can still convert it on-the-fly server-side using a stream converter like gstreamer