# Play audio from a stream using html

Tags: c#, html, sockets, audio, websocket

I want play a audio stream codec G 711/aLaw in html page. For that, I've a IP adress and a port. I already do that in code behind in c#. It works. (sorry for my no well english)

```
byte[] decodedData = G711.Decode_aLaw(e.Data, 0, e.Data.Length);
m_pWaveOut.Play(decodedData, 0, decodedData.Length);
```

Comment: If it works, what is the problem?

Comment: it works in c# no in html

Comment: Take a look at the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524779/need-a-javascript-html-5-web-player-that-plays-audio-with-g-711-codec-wrapped-in

Comment: Please, how can I convert G711 stream to MP3 stream? gstreamer ? Where can I see a example?